# Get the index of subwords produced by BertTokenizer (in transformers library)

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

`BertTokenizer` can tokenize a sentence to a list of tokens, where some long words e.g. "embeddings" is splitted to several subwords i.e. 'em', '##bed', '##ding', and '##s'.

**Is there a way to locate the subwords?** For example,

```
t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

tokens = t('word embeddings', add_special_tokens=False)
location = locate_subwords(tokens)
```

I want the `location` be like `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` corresponding to `['word', 'em', '##bed', '##ding', '##s']`, where 0 means normal word, 1 means subword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fast tokenizers return a [Batchencoding](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#batchencoding) object that has a built-in [word_ids](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.BatchEncoding.word_ids):

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

t = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

tokens = t('word embeddings are vectors', add_special_tokens=False, return_attention_mask=False, return_token_type_ids=False)
print(tokens.word_ids())
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```